# Среднее арифметическое число строки с помощью потоков

Tags: java

Я создала матрицу с рандомными и с положительными числами и возникает такой вопрос: как можно найти  среднее арифметическое число каждой строки через потоки
например, у нас есть матрица:

```
7 8 9
6 5 3
2 1 8
```

и надо посчитать
среднее арифмtтическое число каждой строки но **через потоки**

```
7+6+9/3=7,3
6+5+3=14/3=4.6
2+1+8=11/3=3.6
```

Вот код где я создаю матрицу с рандомными положительными числами:

```
   public class Matrice extends Thread {
    public void createMatrix() {
        int[][] a = new int[3][3];
        int sum;
        int suma = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
                a[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1);

            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++, System.out.println()) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Пожалуйста подскажите как найти  среднее арифмитическое число строки в матрице именно с помощью потоков

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matrix = new int[3][3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
            matrix[i / 3][i % 3] = i + 1;
        }
        final int[] row_average = {0, 0, 0};
        Thread t1 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                int sum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
                    sum += matrix[0][i];
                }
                row_average[0] = sum / 3;
            }
        };
        t1.start();
        Thread t2 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                int sum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
                    sum += matrix[1][i];
                }
                row_average[1] = sum / 3;
            }
        };
        t2.start();
        Thread t3 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                int sum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
                    sum += matrix[2][i];
                }
                row_average[2] = sum / 3;
            }
        };
        t3.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
            t3.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("First row average: " + row_average[0]);
        System.out.println("Second row average: " + row_average[1]);
        System.out.println("Third row average: " + row_average[2]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Matrice {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int[][] array = createMatrix(3,3);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++, System.out.println()) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
            }
        }

        for (int[] arr : array) {
            System.out.println(avg(arr));
        }
    }
    
    public static int[][] createMatrix(int sizeX, int sizeY) {        
        int[][] array = new int[sizeX][sizeY];        
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                array[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1);
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
    
    public static double avg(int[] array) {
        return Arrays.stream(array).average().getAsDouble();
    }
    
}
```

Не пишите весь код в одном методе. Помните про принцип единой ответсвенности. Например, метод createMatrix в моей реализации создает двухмерную рандомную матрицу. Это все, что он делает и именно это и есть единая ответсвенность. А метод avg считает среднее арифметическое из массива и больше ничего. Такие постые методы легче читать и куда легче переиспользовать

Comment: я тоже так думала но в этом коде не используется класс Thread a мне нужно его использовать

Comment: @Tanea так используйте, кто вам мешает?

Comment: я не знаю как но спасибо Вам большое за код

Comment: @Tanea в вашем коде наследовние от класса Thread не дает ровным счетом ничего. этот класс нужен для реализации многопоточности , а для этого нужно переопределить метод run. но это никак не касается вопроса, заключающегося в поиске среднего арифметического с помощью стримов.

Answer (score 0):

Или так

```
package test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] array = new int[3][3];
    IntStream.range(0, 3)
        .forEach(
            i -> IntStream.range(0, 3).forEach(j -> array[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1)));

    Arrays.stream(array)
        .forEach(
            item -> {
              IntStream.of(item).forEach(num -> System.out.print(num + " "));
              System.out.println();
            });

    Arrays.stream(array)
        .map(item -> IntStream.of(item).average().getAsDouble())
        .forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```

Comment: Мне нужно код написать  через потоки мне нужно этот код написать с помощью класса Thread