# Cреднее арифметическое число только положительных чисел

Tags: java

Имеется код где я считаю среднее арифметическое число  всех рядов матрицы ,то есть например: у меня есть матрица

```
7 8 9 -> 7+ 8+ 9=24.3=8
5 5 3  ->  5+5+3=13.3=4,3
8 1 2   -> 8+1+2=11.3=3,6
```

Вот код :

```
public class MatrixThread extends Thread {

    public void createMatrix() {
        int[][] a = new int[3][3];


        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
                a[i][j] = (int) (Math.random()*100)+1;


            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++, System.out.println()) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
            }
        }

        final double[] row_average = {0, 0, 0};
        Thread t1 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                int sum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
                    if (i > 0) {

                        sum += a[0][i]; 
                    }

                    row_average[0] = (double) sum / a.length;
                }
            }
        };
        t1.start();
        Thread t2 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                int sum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
                    if (i > 0) {

                        sum += a[1][i];
                    }
                    row_average[1] = (double) sum / 3;
                }
            }
        };
        t2.start();
        Thread t3 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                int sum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
                    if (i > 0) {
                        sum += a[2][i];
                    }
                    row_average[2] = (double) sum / 3;
                }
            }
        };
        t3.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
            t3.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("First row average: " + row_average[0]);
        System.out.println("Second row average: " + row_average[1]);
        System.out.println("Third row average: " + row_average[2]);
    }
}
```

Вопрос как я могу ввести матрицу с клавиатуры а не рандомно и как мне сделать что бы считалась арифметическое число только положительных чисел
Например

7 -1 8 -7+8=15.2=>7,5
-1 не берется в счет так как оно отрицательное число
Пожалуйста добавьте вот эти 2 пункта в мой код

Comment: То есть просто сделать за Вас?

Comment: я правда не знаю как я вот написала код а вот как выполнить эти 2 пункта не знаю ,просто помогите с этими двумя пунктами я обещаю что я их изучу как делать

Comment: Вы знаете как проверить, является ли число положительным?

Comment: знаю (if a[i]>0){

Comment: но как убрать негативные числа что б их не брать в счет  не знаю

Comment: не прибавлять их к `sum`

Comment: вот в этом и проблема у меня я могу проверить если число положительное или нет но вот как сделать что бы суммировались только положительные числа и что бы делилилось только на количество положительных чисел в строке не знаю

Comment: и кстати я так и делаю   if (i > 0) {

                        sum += a[1][i];
                    }  но все равно берут в счет и негативные числа тоже

Comment: `if (a[1][i] > 0) { sum += a[1][i]; } `

Comment: так тоже не работает

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Среднее арифметическое число строки с помощью потоков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1267989/%d0%a1%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            int sum = 0, count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
                if (a[0][i] > 0) {
                    sum += a[0][i];
                    count++; 
                }
            }
            if (count > 0)
                row_average[0] = (double) sum / count;
```

Answer (score 0):

а если такой вариант

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class test {
    private static final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int t=scan.nextInt();      // количество матриц(3шт)
        for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
            int number = scan.nextInt(); //число матрицы(567)
            System.out.println(summNumber(Math.abs(number)));

        }

    }
    public static double summNumber(int n) {
        int m = 0;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<!G.)");   
        String[] strArr = pattern.split(Integer.toString(n)); // n --> []strArr
        int[] intArr = new int[strArr.length];
        for (int j = 0; j < strArr.length; j++) {       // []strArr --> []intArr
            intArr[j] = Integer.parseInt(strArr[j]);
            m += intArr[j];                             // summ []intArr --> n
        }
        return (double)m/strArr.length;
    }

}
```

Comment: нет такой вариант не подойдет нужно именно с потоками как сделала я