# Используя поток как посчитать сумму соседей матрицы

Tags: java, многопоточность

Подскажите пожалуйста как посчитать сумму соседей матрицы
например имеется матрица 
3 5 7 =>3+7=10

   8 9 7 =>8+7=15

  6 5 4=>10
Логику я понимаю нужно сделать по этой формуле sum = a[i-1][i] + a[i+1][i]
но это нужно сделать в самом  потоке и это для меня проблема
Вот я написала код:

```
public class MatrixThread  extends Thread {

static int total;

public void createMatrix() {
    int[][] a = new int[3][3];


    Object monitor = new Object();

    synchronized (monitor) {
        monitor.notifyAll();

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
                Random random = new Random();
                a[i][j] = -6 + random.nextInt(100 - 36);//-6 до 99.
             

            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++, System.out.println()) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
        }
    }


    final double[] row_average = {0, 0, 0};


  Thread t1 = new Thread() {
   public void run() {
     int sum = 0, count = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
         if (a[1][i] > 0) {
             sum += a[1][i];
             count++;
         }

     }
     if (count > 0)
         row_average[1] = (double) sum / count;
 }


 


    };

    t1.start();
    synchronized (t1) {
        try {
            t1.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



                Thread t2 = new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        int sum = 0, count = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
                            if (a[1][i] > 0) {
                                sum += a[1][i];
                                count++;
                            }

                        }
                        if (count > 0)
                            row_average[1] = (double) sum / count;
                    }
                };

                t2.start();
                synchronized (t2) {
                    try {
                        t2.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // t2.notify();
                }
                Thread t3 = new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        int sum = 0, count = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
                            if (a[2][i] > 0) {
                                sum += a[2][i];
                                count++;
                            }
                        }
                        if (count > 0)
                            row_average[2] = (double) sum / count;
                    }

                };
                t3.start();
                synchronized (t3) {
                    try {
                        t3.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //  t3.notify();
                }

                try {

                    t1.join();
                    t2.join();
                    t3.join();

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println("First row average: " + row_average[0]);
                System.out.println("Second row average: " + row_average[1]);
                System.out.println("Third row average: " + row_average[2]);
            }
        }
    };
```

и вот когда я ищу сумму соседних элементов матрицы то выдает ошибку этот метод нужно  добавить  именно в Thread t1,Thread t2,Thread t3 и вот этого я как раз этого не понимаю разве 1 поток не делает только одну функцию ,разве он может делать много ,разных функций?
Пожалуйста, помогите мне уже как третий день учу потоки и сижу над этой задачей

Comment: **(1)** Синхронизацию (если она нужна) необходимо делать на объекте, который виден  другим потокам. У тебя синхронизация делается на локальном объекте (`Object monitor = new Object();`). **(2)** Зачем делать ожидание на потоке (`t1.wait`)? Программа остановится здесь навсегда. Достаточно делать `join`, как у тебя делается в конце. **(3)** В условии про соседей, в коде - среднее. Чей-то чужой код?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Cреднее арифметическое число только положительных чисел](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1268778/c%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb)

Answer (score 0):

Не хочу писать тебе код, иначе ничему не научишься.

Правильная программа д.б. примерно такой

1. Создать объект `monitor`, который будет виден всем потокам.
2. Создать и заполнить матрицу
3. Создать объект, куда потоки будут записывать результаты
4. Создать и запустить потоки, которые занимаются своей порцией вычислений. 
   4.1. Каждый поток должен вычислить свои данные 
   4.2. Каждый поток должен записать свои данные внутри секции синхронизации на объекте, созданном в п.1 
   `synchronized (monitor) { /*записать результаты в объект, созданный в п.3*/ }` 
   4.3 Поток должен выйти из метода `run`, что будет означать завершение его работы
5. Основная программа в это время ждёт завершения всех созданных потоков, используя `t.join()`
6. Основная программа печатает результат внутри секции синхронизации на объекте, созданном в п.1 
   `synchronized (monitor) { /*распечатать результаты из объекта, созданного в п.3*/ }`